# Spring session destroy event differentiate between session timeout and logout

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc, session-timeout

I have a Spring application where I have a class that extends HttpSessionEventPublisher.

I am albe to track the session destroy events.

But now I want to distinguish whether the session is destroyed due to session timeout or due to explicit logout by user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking through the [HttpSessionEventPublisher API](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/session/HttpSessionEventPublisher.html), it looks like you can use the `HttpSessionDestroyedEvent` which is passed as in argument in the `sessionDestroyed()` method.

You can do something **like** the following:

```
javax.servlet.http.HttpSession session = event.getSession();
long lastAction = session.getLastAccessedTime();
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
int timeout= getMaxInactiveInterval();
if ((now-lastAction) > timeout)
   //the session has timed out

SecurityContext context = getSecurityContext();
Authentication authentication = context.getAuthentication();
if (!authentication.isAuthenticated())
   //the user has logged out
```